# How to select a single object by id using @ngrx/entity

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-entity

Using @ngrx/entity I want to select an entity by a single id or an array of entities by an array of ids from an entity map.

I do not want the select subscriptions inside a component to be triggered when the entity collection gets a new element or an entity item changes, which I did not select at all.

This obviously happens to me when I use the selectEntities selector and then pick the IDs from the result.

So how can I select 1 or n items by id from an entity collection?

Answer (score 34):

**EDIT:** as Ethan mentions below, [selectors with `props` were deprecated in v12](https://ngrx.io/guide/migration/v12). This decision was [discussed extensively in an RFC](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/2980). (Comments further down the thread address [how to effectively memoise factory functions](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/2980#issuecomment-857092137).)

The currently recommended approach to this is using a **factory function**:

```js
export const selectEntity = id => createSelector(
  selectEntities,
  entities => entities[id]
);

export const selectEntitiesByID = ids => createSelector(
  selectEntities,
  entities => ids.map(id => entities[id])
);
```

Which are called thus:

```js
this.store.pipe(
  select(selectEntity(someID))
);

this.store.pipe(
  select(selectEntitiesByID(arrayOfIDs))
);
```

---

Previously, NgRx supported **parameterised selectors** by [passing `props` as the last argument to a selector function](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/selectors#using-selectors-with-props):

```js
export const selectEntity = createSelector(
  selectEntities,
  (entities, props) => entities[props.id]
);

export const selectEntitiesByID = createSelector(
  selectEntities,
  (entities, props) => props.ids.map(id => entities[id])
);
```

These are invoked exactly as you might expect:

```js
this.store.pipe(
  select(selectEntity, { id: someID })
);

this.store.pipe(
  select(selectEntitiesByID, { ids: arrayOfIDs })
);
```

Comment: Downvotes are a helpful signal that something might be wrong or missing, and I appreciate you taking the time, but a comment would be really helpful—otherwise, I'm left guessing at how I might have missed the mark! For now, I'm not sure, so I'll leave my answer as it stands.

Comment: Does the selector "selectEntitiesByID" memoize the results? If instead of returning a flat array of Entities, what if it constructs a new Dictionary with only those Entities requested? Will that be memoized? I guess the question is how does the memoization compare for equality?

Comment: Thanks for letting me know @EthanSK, updated now! :)

Answer (score 3):

Besides `entities` and `ids` I also add a `selectedEntityId` on my state doing on a User Example:

```js
    import {User} from '../models/user.model';
    import {EntityState, createEntityAdapter} from '@ngrx/entity';

    export interface UsersState extends EntityState<User> {
      // additional entities state properties
      selectedUserId: number | null;
    }
```

And the selectors would look like this:

```js
    export const selectUserEntities = selectEntities;
    
    export const getSelectedUserId = (state: UsersState) => state.selectedUserId;
    
    export const selectCurrentUser = createSelector(
      selectUserEntities,
      getSelectedUserId,
      (userEntities, userId) => userEntities[userId]
    );
```

Comment: This will work to select a single entity. But to select n entities by id, it looks like the previous response is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Selectors with props are deprecated, for more info see [RFC: Deprecate Selectors With Props](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/2980).

However, a type safe alternative is demonstrated in [RFC 2980](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/2980). Applied to the answer from @jordan-gray:

```js
export const selectEntity = (props: { id: number }) =>
  createSelector(selectEntities, (entities) => {
    return entities[props.id];
  });
```

Called with

```js
this.store.select(selectEntity({ id: myId }));
```

Answer (score 1):

For both scenarios I would handle it with dedicated selector:

```js
    // single entity
    export const singleEntitySelector = createSelector(

       // you should have set it up already 
       yourEntitiesObjSelector,

       // here I assume you have set up router reducer state or any other 
    state slice where you keep single entity id
       yourIdSelector,

       // then you just return single entity as entities will be an object
       (entities, id) => entities[id]
    );

    // same for array (you will have to store selected ids also on the 
    state tree)
    export const selectedEntitiesArraySelector = createSelector(

       // you should have set it up already 
       yourEntitiesObjSelector,

       // here I assume you have set up selected ids store slice
       yourSelectedIdsArraySelector,

       // then you just return entities array reducing ids array
       (entities, idsArray) => idsArray.reduce((acc, id) => {
          return entities[id] ? [...acc, entities[id]] : acc;
       }, [])
    );
```

Then you will just use those selectors in your component, reflecting changes in the view with `async` pipe as usual. They will reflect all the changes: either there was a single entity id change or ids array change. Do not need to subscribe to anything, unless there is some additional logic in your component.